# C++ interop with C# via ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop

My application is mainly developped by C++ on Windows platform. Now I want to integrate some fancy features implemented by C# into my app.

The way I call C# code from C++ is [ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164411.aspx), which requires the method signiture of C# is `static int pwzMethodName (String pwzArgument)`.

**The problem is how can I pass a pointer of an instance C++ class as the pwzArgument into the calling method, and consume the native C++ class from C# code directly?**

For example, I have the following C++ code and C# code,

```
// C++ code
struct IUserContext
{
    virtual const char* GetCompany() const = 0;
    virtual const char* GetUser() const = 0;
};
class UserContextImpl : public IUserContext
{
public:
    virtual const char* GetCompany() const { return m_company.c_str(); }
    virtual const char* GetUser() const { return m_user.c_str(); }
private:
    std::string m_company; // will be assigned in constructor
    std::string m_user;
};
int main()
{
    ICLRRuntimeHost *pClrHost = CreateHost();
    UserContextImpl user;
    IUserContext& cx = user;
    DWORD dwRet;

    wstringstream param;
    param << (void*)&cx;

    pClrHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
        L"MySharpAssembly.dll",
        L"MyCompany.Namespace.MyClass", 
        L"Start", 
        param.str().c_str(), 
        &dwRet);
    //...
}

// C# code
namespace MyCompany.Namespace
{
    interface IUserContext
    {
        string GetCompany();
        string GetUser();
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static int Start(string pwzArgument)
        {
            IntPtr pointer = (IntPtr)int.Parse(pwzArgument, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            // How to implement this "MagicMarshal.GetInterface" method? 
            IUserContext cx = MagicMarshal.GetInterface<IUserContext>(pointer);
            MessageBox.Show(cx.GetUser());
        }
    }
}
```